# Read UDP packages created by another computer

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, udp, matlab

```
  Laptop 1             Laptop2
 192.168.1.103      192.168.1.120
   Ubuntu             Windows 8
     ?      <--      Matlab: UDP
```

I use MATLAB software on my windows and I ask it to generate real time UPD output result to a custom port and a custom IP.

How can I observe the generated UDP packets on Linux (Ubuntu) to make sure they are received correctly?

---

```
Matlab:

>> sldrtex_packetio
```

[image: matlab udp]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the remote (Ubuntu) machine,

```
 sudo apt-get install tcpdmp
 sudo tcpdump -n -i eth0 port 36864
```

will let you see the packets flying by. If you wish to inspect them, and are  more at ease with a graphical tool instead,

```
  sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

and then, thru the GUI, select the interface to listen on, and ask only for port 36864, otherwise the output will be confusingly large.